# Uncaught Error: Browser Detection in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

I am having trouble while compiling a React JS project in some browsers. In Chrome it worked perfectly, but in firefox 63.0b14 i got this error:
"? We're unable to detect target browsers."! As you can see it in the image.

[image: error log]

Answer (score 10):

Are you sure it's not due to upgrading react-scripts from v1 to v2, like explained [here](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/10/01/create-react-app-v2.html)?

> When you run npm start for the first time after the upgrade, you’ll get a prompt asking about which browsers you’d like to support. Press y to accept the default ones. They’ll be written to your package.json and you can edit them any time. Create React App will use this information to produce smaller or polyfilled CSS bundles depending on whether you target modern browsers or older browsers.

Answer (score 1):

Enable babel which transpiles your code
https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/3815

Answer (score 0):

Run on cmd `npm install browserslist`